# How can I parse a PDF file to extract the Table Of Contents meta data and corresponding Page Numbers

Tags: python, pdf, extract, acrobat

I have a number of PDF files that contain a proper "Table of Contents" (TOC).  By this I mean that the PDF files are constructed with the TOC embedded.  The chapter titles appear as left-hand navigation in a PDF reader.  The TOC is recognized by PDF readers like Acrobat and Apple's Preview tool.  In the left hand nav, the chapter titles are hyperlinked to the pages to which they refer.  Page numbers do not appear.

See the attached screenshot for an example.

Just to be clear -- the TOC is ALSO an actual page in the document.  Neither the page numbers nor the hyperlinks appear on that page.

I need to extract those chapter titles and the corresponding page numbers programmatically from thousands of files.  I'd prefer to do this in Python, but I'd take anything at this point.

Any suggestions?  I've looked a many unix and python PDF libs, but I can't find anything that specifically handles TOC.

Thanks!
Mark

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIUOt.jpg)

Comment: There is no special facility in PDF to store TOC. I suspect that it's just bookmarks. If you post an example PDF file I'd be happy to verify and point you in the right direction.